# How to regenerate APP_KEY and set new passwords in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, environment-variables

Today I restore my Macbook OS Yosemite and I forgot to backup my `.env` file, so I lost my `APP_KEY`.

Now all my paswords not work anymore and I understand that. So I do that:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Then I update all passwords using this code:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $users = new Project\DB\User;
    $users->update(['password' => Hash::make('newPasswordHere')]);
});
```

But when I try to update an user using the system and I change the password, I can't login. That's the code of `update($id)` method:

```
$user = User::getById($id);

$user->role_id = $request->get('role_id');
$user->first_name = $request->get('first_name');
$user->last_name = $request->get('last_name');
$user->email = $request->get('email');

if ($request->has('password')) {
    $user->password = Hash::make($request->get('password'));
}

$user->active = $request->get('active');
$user->update();
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

### My setup

- Macbook Pro - Yosemite
- PHP-FPM - `PHP 5.6.11 (cli) (built: Jul 19 2015 15:15:07)`
- Nginx - `nginx version: nginx/1.8.0`

---

If you need more information, tell me please.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that was the problem, but I must tell them the real cause and solution:

At the beginning of the project I was set a mutator to **password** attribute.

This mutator in turn was already encrypting the password (yes ... I know, I do not believe I did not see it).

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($value);
}
```

Finally, the solution of the problem was not encrypt the password on the controller:

```
if ($request->has('password')) {
    $user->password = $request->get('password');
}
```

Sorry and thank you for your time!